# expand child ul on click of parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="Downloadscontainer">
<ul>
    <li>level 1</li>
    <li><a href="#">level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>level 2</li>
             <li>level 2</li>
             <li><a href="#">some page</a>
            <ul>
                <li>level 2</li>
                <li>level 2</li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And i am trying to display ul on click of its parent li, following is my jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Downloadscontainer ul li ul").css("display", "none");
    $(".Downloadscontainer li").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
                $('.Downloadscontainer li ul').toggle();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So if I click on level 1 `LI` it displays the `UL` and then if I click on level 2 `LI` which have `UL` as well it close down the `UL` of level 1 `LI`; I would like it to keep opening the child `UL`. How can I obtain this functionality ?

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ot0kxs0z/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ot0kxs0z/2/

```
 $(".Downloadscontainer li").click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
 });
```

notes:

- You do not need to `each` to attach handlers to multiple elements in jQuery.
- You just need to stop the child click propagating to the parent LI in DOM
- As `@George` suggests you may be better off attaching to the anchor click.

Taking the anchor approach I would suggest the following as *DOM-change friendly*:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ot0kxs0z/5/

```
 $(".Downloadscontainer a").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest('li').children('ul').toggle();
 });
```

Notes:

- It finds the closest `LI` to the anchor clicked, then drills down to the child `UL`s (rather than navigate via `next`, which required a known arrangement.
- `preventDefault` will stop blank bookmark links (`href="#"` in your example) from scrolling to the top of the page. If they were full links they would stop them navigating, so you may need an additional check if you add page  links.

e.g you can check if the link is a blank bookmark and allow other links to fire normally:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ot0kxs0z/7/

```
 $(".Downloadscontainer a").click(function (e) {
     if ($(this).attr("href") == '#') {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest('li').children('ul').toggle();
     }
 });
```

This fiddle has an external link to Google, as well as the `#` links.

Comment: thanks for giving notes :) now i got the better understanding of it  .

Answer (score 3):

How about attaching your event handler to the anchor?:

```
$(".Downloadscontainer li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ot0kxs0z/3/)

- Remember, prevent the default action of your anchor so as not to be redirected, should it have a link.
- `.each()` looping is not neccessary for many jQuery methods, event handling binder methods like `.click()`, `.change()`, `.keydown()`, etc. included.

Comment: The anchors are bookmark links, so will not redirect, but your solution will avoid the browser jumping up to the top of the page so should be added to any answer. +1

Comment: Sure, I don't know where this code could be going though. You make a good point none-the-less. (:

Comment: Thanks @George for you help :) i want to accept both of the answers but unfortunately can accept only one :(

Comment: Of course! Glad to have helped. TrueBlueAussie provided an answer as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it's succes, you can use it

```
$(".main-menu li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle().css("padding-left", "30px");
});
```

i added some extra feture for padding-left each children ul , so that we can understand/ desfine which one is expanded.