# CSS overlay with menu collapsible

Tags: html, css

How i make the child lists expand and collapse by click ?

```
.tree-list li > ul{
display: none;
}
```

See the Pen [Pure CSS Fullscreen Overlay Menu](http://codepen.io/josemansilva/pen/aWEaGY/) .

Comment: Which lists you want to expand/collapse by click on which button ?

Comment: all entries have sub lists, i want click on parent and expand

Comment: Do you want implement this with css or jQuery is ok for you ?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423230/expand-child-ul-on-click-of-parent-li). Remove href from parent otherwise clicking parent will redirect you to another page which is written in href

Comment: @nimish im trying only with pure css + html , btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by jquery/javascript or you can simply use css for hover.
for jquery just write onclick ul display:block along with this css.

```
<nav id="dropdown">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

In CSS

```
    #dropdown
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#dropdown ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#dropdown ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#dropdown ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}


#dropdown ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

#dropdown ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

#dropdown ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#dropdown ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#dropdown ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#dropdown ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

Comment: you can add more styles as like you specified in the Pen.